# Fedora 35 PHP 8.0 / 8.1 Warning: PHP Startup: ^(text/|application/xhtml\+xml) (offset=0

Tags: php, warnings, startup, fedora

I am using Fedora Linux ver 35 with PHP 8.0.x but recently encountered below error and the php codes failed to work.

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: ^(text/|application/xhtml+xml) (offset=0): unrecognised compile-time option bit(s) in Unknown on line 0

I tried

1. installing / upgrading it to 8.1 but still received the same error
2. also tried apt update and apt upgrade but with no effect

I read other solutions, seem to be for debian os.

Appreciate anyone can offer some help?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1682

Comment: If you're stuck you could consider using Docker (https://hub.docker.com/_/php)